# no method is calling in recylcerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here, only the constructor is calling and data is being passed in the arraylist but nothing else happens, no other function is calling -

adapter code

```
public class RentCarRecyclerAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RentCarRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    public  static   ArrayList<RentCarHolder> dataList;
    Context context;


    public RentCarRecyclerAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<RentCarHolder> list) {
        context = c;
        dataList = list;


    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView carimage;
        TextView carname, rentprice, ageofdriver, numberofdoors, maxpeople, airconditioned, mileage, transmission, status;
        Button booknow;
        ProgressBar progressBar;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            carimage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.carpic);
            carname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.carname);
            rentprice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rentprice);
            ageofdriver = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.minimumdriverage);
            numberofdoors = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.doorcount);
            maxpeople = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.maxpeople);
            airconditioned = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.airconditioned);
            mileage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.unlimitedmilage);
            transmission = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.transmission);
            booknow = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.book);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);


        }
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_rentacar, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);


        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.carname.setText(dataList.get(position).getCarname());
        holder.rentprice.setText(dataList.get(position).getRentprice());
        holder.ageofdriver.setText(dataList.get(position).getAgeofdriver());
        holder.numberofdoors.setText(dataList.get(position).getNumberofdoors());
        holder.maxpeople.setText(dataList.get(position).getMaxpeople());
        holder.airconditioned.setText(dataList.get(position).getAirconditioned());
        holder.mileage.setText(dataList.get(position).getMileage());
        holder.transmission.setText(dataList.get(position).getTransmission());
        holder.status.setText(dataList.get(position).getStatus());


        Glide.with(context)
            .load(dataList.get(position).getCarimageURL())

            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into(holder.carimage);
            holder.booknow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CarBookingActivity.class).putExtra("position",position));
                }
            });

     }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }


}
```

xml code

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/carshowrecycler"
    android:layout_below="@id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:orientation="horizontal"


    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
/>
```

I have followed the solutions of many answers but none have helped. I have been working on it for last 3-4 hours and have researched many answers on stack overflow but nothing has helped
please help me!

activity code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="belllab.naseem.tourism.Activities.RentACarActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/locallayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/localairporttext"
            android:text=" Local/Airport Pick / Drop"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/localairportview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#7e7c7c" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/outstationlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/outstationtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"


            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="OutStation"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/outstationview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#7e7c7c" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/selflayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selfvehicle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Self Driven Vehicle"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/selfvehicleview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#7e7c7c" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/carshowrecycler"
    android:layout_below="@id/menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:orientation="horizontal"


    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
/>


  </RelativeLayout>
```

set adapter code

```
 RentCarRecyclerAdapter adapter =    new RentCarRecyclerAdapter(RentACarActivity.this,list);
                    carsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

row code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <LinearLayout

       android:layout_above="@+id/book"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height_for_car">

        <ImageView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/carpic"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
      />
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            />
      </RelativeLayout>

          <TextView
          android:id="@+id/carname"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:text="Taxi"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"

          />

          <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         android:background="@color/transparentview"
        />
           <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="availiable"
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
        </RelativeLayout>


         <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Price per day"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="RS 7,600"
            android:id="@+id/rentprice"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
      </RelativeLayout>
      <View
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transparentview"
        />
        <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Max People"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:id="@+id/maxpeople"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"




                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="10" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Door Count"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:id="@+id/doorcount"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"




                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="10" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Minimum driver age"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:id="@+id/minimumdriverage"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"




                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="10" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Transmission"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:id="@+id/transmission"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"




                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="10" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Air Conditioned?"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:id="@+id/airconditioned"




                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="10" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Unlimited mileage?"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:id="@+id/unlimitedmilage"




                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="10" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

      </LinearLayout>
         <View
          android:layout_above="@+id/book"
           android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         android:background="@color/transparentview"
        />

         <Button


        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/book"
        android:text="Book Now"
        android:background="@drawable/bookbuttonbackground"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no other function is calling" ? Don't you see your data on screen? You are fetching the data and setting to your list, what else you are expecting?

Comment: data is not showing on the screen

Comment: whats the exact problem ?? and post your activity code too..

Comment: no other function is calling it means no bindview none other function is calling for adapter

Comment: data is not showing in recyclerview

Comment: post your activity code..

Comment: and orientation horizontal ..?? what does it have to do with recyclerView ??

Comment: to slide recylcerview to slide in horizontol direction

Comment: then post just the `setAdapter` code along with the data fetching list..

Comment: data is fetching from server

Comment: i m afraid ...if you dont post the activity code ..in this case nobody can solve this issue ..

Comment: i have posted the code kindly review the question again

Comment: hello sir where u go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem in your code is code is that your are using the layout manager both in xml and in java code remove any one of them
any secondly verify it that you use either design compile or recylcerview compile in gradle not the both
make sure in code you didn't make the recylcerview visibility gone

Comment: i dont know why but this help

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your adapter code

Remove this line from your XML `app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`

You need to get the recyclerView in your activity like this

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.carshowrecycler);
RentCarRecyclerAdapter adapter = new RentCarRecyclerAdapter (this,dataList);

LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
```

then assign layoutManager and adapter to your recyclerView like this

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: in design view in  your activity XML do you see recycler view list

Comment: pleease heck if have post it

Comment: okay you need to change ** android:layout_height="match_parent"** to wrap_content in your row layout dont use 
 **android:layout_height="match_parent"** in any view inside your row

Comment: if you want, you can give me repo of this project so I can fix this issue for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is missing this for the RecyclerView:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(runningActivity));
```

I forget it every time and wonder why nothing is displayed (same effect) .
I do not know why, but after a LayoutManager is assigned to the Recylerview, it works.

Comment: You set the adapter onle one time? Or in base of an update will be reassigned the adapter?

Comment: only once it is set